# Are there any High-Throughput studies that aim to discover High Tc superconductors?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, high-performance-computing, materials-informatics, superconductivity

High-Throughput materials modeling based on Density Functional Theory has become very popular recently. If, for example, we search ["High-Throughput Perovskites"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=High-Throughput%20perovskites&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) in Google Scholar, we get over ~14,000 results. Not all are computational and not all are peer-reviewed publications but it shows just how important High Performance Computing is in current materials research. Needless to say, [The Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/) and [AFLOW](http://aflowlib.org/) are big players in the High-Throughput Materials Simulation game. There is even a [database](https://www.topologicalquantumchemistry.org/#/) for Topological Insulators and Weyl Semimetals

However I am not aware of a database or High-Throughput study that is completely focused on the discovery of high $T_C$ superconductors. Can anyone point me toward some references? Are there any studies of this kind at all?

Comment: If Geoff has answered your question you may want to accept their answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several such studies, particularly focusing on the machine-learning of critical temperatures.

- ["Machine learning modeling of superconducting critical temperature"](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41524-018-0085-8)
- ["An acceleration search method of higher T c superconductors by a machine learning algorithm"](https://doi.org/10.7567/1882-0786/ab2922)
- ["Can machine learning identify the next high-temperature superconductor? Examining extrapolation performance for materials discovery"](https://doi.org/10.1039/C8ME00012C)

They all rely on the ["Supercon"](https://supercon.nims.go.jp/index_en.html) database of ~12,000 critical temperatures, which has also been extracted as supporting information for the first paper to [GitHub](https://github.com/vstanev1/Supercon).

In general, the ML methods offer suggestions for new compositions, but I'm not sure if any have yet been attempted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Geoff! I was sure there had to be some recent studies out there that tackled this problem. I will read them with care, as I confess I do not know how one would go about modeling superconductors, but have always wanted to take a crack at it.